# PHP if else Request URI help

Tags: php, syntax

I tried doing this but then it is not working

```
 <?php

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='http://www.testground.idghosting.com/idi' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'our-production/') {

         echo '<div id="services">
<h1>Our services</h1>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_productions" title="Our Productions"><span>Our Productions</span></a>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_services" title="Production Services"><span>Production Services</span></a>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_equipment" title="Equipment &amp; Facilities"><span>Equipment &amp; Facilities</span></a>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_pr" title="PR &amp; Media"><span>PR &amp; Media</span></a>

</div>';
     } else {
         echo '<div> do not show</div>';
     } ;
 ?>
```

to see the sample [click here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/idi/) see the block where it says Our services in the bottom I don't want it to be shown on ths page but visible to all other pages....

Comment: and why, can I ask, did you try this? have anyone on here suggested it? you've completely changed your answer, that's not nice at all.

Comment: I have tried all the suggested answer here and it didn't worked..... I haven't changed anything I just applied one of the suggestion here and to ask programmers who has more experienced than me.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always indent your code — it's simplier to see errors

```
 <?php
     if ($url == "http://www.sample.com/test.php") {
         echo "<div>whatever</div>";
     } else {
         echo "<div> do not show</div>";
     };
 ?>
```

Note the placement of curly brackets.

Comment: I'm being pedantic here i think, but his syntax was fine except that he was missing the word echo directly after 'else'.  But yes syntax was weird, but legal I think?

Comment: My IDE says syntax is not legal. You cannot place string after opening curly brace.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use the ternary operator. All on one line if you like - I broke it up to avoid the evil scrollbars.

```
echo ($url == "http://www.sample.com/test.php") 
       ? "<div>Whatever</div>" 
       : "";
```

Comment: "I broke it up to avoid the evil scrollbars" - obvious reason to *not* do it in one-liner :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='www.sample.com' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/test.php') {
  echo 'blah';
} else {
  echo 'asdf';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re using the wrong values.

```
// REQUEST_URI is the requested URI path plus the requested URI query, so let’s strip the latter
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// HTTP_HOST may not be set if the request didn’t contain the Host header field (just HTTP/1.0)
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='www.testground.idghosting.com' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] == '/idi/our-production/') {
    // host is "www.testground.idghosting.com" and requested URI path is "/idi/our-production/"
}
```

See the manual for what values the [`$_SERVER`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($url == "http://www.sample.com/test.php")
    {
        echo "<div>whatever</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div> do not show</div>";
    }
?>
```

Your syntax was just a little wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There does not currently seem to be a direct way. What you’ll have to do is to reconstruct the  URL by combining entries from the [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/$_server) array. You can check the results of the [phpinfo()](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) to see what entries you need.

Answer (score 0):

At a higher level, have you considered changing your approach for getting this onto the pages where you want it?  You could put the section within the then part of your code into a separate file which you [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) into those files in which you want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in the echo string, you open a php tag, but that is already php code, so you don't have to open that tag.
You'd have to one one if you were in HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

try this and it is working for me ...

```
$data['test']=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

if($data['test'] == 'our-production')
{
 echo '<div id="services">
<h1>Our services</h1>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_productions" title="Our Productions"><span>Our Productions</span></a>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_services" title="Production Services"><span>Production Services</span></a>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_equipment" title="Equipment &amp; Facilities"><span>Equipment &amp; Facilities</span></a>
<a href="<?php bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>" id="serv_pr" title="PR &amp; Media"><span>PR &amp; Media</span></a>

</div>';
 } else {
 echo '<div> do not show</div>';
 } ;

}
```